# Assigning 2 lambdas from a tuple using tie

Tags: c++, function, lambda, auto

I have a function which returns a `std::tuple` of lambdas and i want to assign each lambda to a variable using `std::tie()`

```
#include<tuple>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto fn(){
    auto f1 = []() {cout << "ran 1" << endl;};
    auto f2 = []() {cout << "ran 2" << endl;};
    return make_tuple(f1, f2);
}

int main()
{
    auto res = fn();
    auto f1,f2; // doesn't compile
    tie(f1, f2) = res;

    f1();
    f2();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that lambdas have to be from type '`auto`' since they are resolved at compile time, but i cannot declare variables as `auto` without defining them. So what can i do to get this code to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++17 introduced [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) that will do this for you.  Using

```
const auto& [f1, f2] = fn();
```

will create a reference to the returned object extending it's lifetime and introduce `f1` and `f2` as names to the members of the tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from C++17, you can use structured bindings (see other answer).

Before C++17 (C++11 and C++14), you can use `std::get()` with two separate declarations

```
auto f1 = std::get<0>(res);
auto f2 = std::get<1>(res);
```

and, yes: in both cases you've to declare and to define the variables at the same time [edit: this is true until C++20; not necessarily true since C++20]

Because you can obtain the types of `f1` and `f2`, doubling the use of `std::get()`

```
using type_f1 = std::remove_reference_t<decltype((std::get<0>(res)))>;
using type_f2 = std::remove_reference_t<decltype((std::get<1>(res)))>;
```

or, maybe better, using `std::tuple_element`

```
using type_f1 = std::tuple_element_t<0, decltype(res)>;
using type_f2 = std::tuple_element_t<1, decltype(res)>;
```

but this doesn't permit the declaration of `f1` and `f2` without defining them

```
type_f1  f1;  // compilation error (before C++20) !!!
type_f2  f2;  // compilation error (before C++20) !!!
```

because lambdas types lacks [edit: before C++20] of default constructors.

Edit: as pointed by Nathan Oliver (thanks!), starting from C++20, lambda with empty capture list have enabled the default constructor.

So, starting from C++20, the following code compile

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

auto fn ()
 { return std::make_tuple(
      []() { std::cout << "ran 1" << std::endl; },
      []() { std::cout << "ran 2" << std::endl; }); }

int main()
 {
   auto res = fn();

   std::tuple_element_t<0u, decltype(res)>  f1;
   std::tuple_element_t<1u, decltype(res)>  f2;

   f1 = std::get<0u>(res);
   f2 = std::get<1u>(res);

   f1();
   f2();
 }
```

Comment: Do note that your last bit will compile in C++20 as long as the lambda has an empty capture list.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica - You're right: with C++20 works. I didn't know at all that C++20 introduce default constructors for lambdas with empty capture list. I have to study C++20. Thanks; answer improved.